# remove only the last tab character from a line of a file python

Tags: python, file

I have a file with all lines ending with a tab space character. I want to remove only the last tab space character. How do i do that??

Eg:

```
"a   b   c   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0   "
```

I want it like

```
"a   b   c   0 0   0 0   0 0   0 0"
```

Comment: You can read in the file to a string, search and replace tabs before a newline (rstrip might be helpful), then write the file back out. Have you tried any of these things?

Comment: @Vignesh He suggested `rstrip()`, which is what you were looking for.

Comment: Also, can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: that helped thanku. I was trying to convert it to an array remove last element and write it back into the file. it was so circumnavigating and wanted a short method to do it.

Comment: If it helped you should probably accept Martijn's answer, since that's the solution he provided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`str.rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to remove characters of the end of a string:

```
somestring.rstrip('\t')
```

You can give it multiple characters; the argument is treated as a *set* and all characters at the end of the string that match that set are removed:

```
somestring.rstrip('\t\n ')
```

would remove all tabs, newlines and spaces from the end of the line.

If you want to remove any whitespace, regardless, call `.rstrip()` without an argument:

```
somestring.rstrip()
```

Comment: i ran this then printed it as a list and it still had 3 spaces at the end

Comment: @ChristianCareaga: Use `print repr(line)` to see what is *really* there.